# Clamp segment inside rectangle

Tags: geometry, collision, intersection, segment

I have a rectangle, and there lines that outgoing from center of it into arbitrary position outside of rectangle. I need to clamp them to rectangle edges, so endpoint will lie on rectangle. I tried using intersection algorithms and it works, but it pretty slow because it handles any kind of collisions, while I have specific conditions: start of segment is always in center of rectangle, and end of line is always outside of rectangle, maybe there some fast algorithm for this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that rectangle dimensions are `width, height` and rectangle center is at `(0,0)`
(otherwise subtract center coordinates from `endx, endy` variables and add them to final results)

```
if abs(endx) * height <= abs(endy) * width   //top or bottom side
    return height/2 * endx / abs(endy),    sign(endy) * height/2
else     //left or right side
    return sign(endx) * width/2,  width/2 * endy / abs(endx)
```

Python quick check:

```
from math import copysign

def rectclamp(rectcenterx, rectcentery, width, height, lineendx, lineendy):
    endx = lineendx - rectcenterx
    endy = lineendy - rectcentery
    if abs(endx) * height <= abs(endy) * width: #at top or bottom
        return (rectcenterx + height / 2 * endx / abs(endy),
                rectcentery + copysign(1, endy) * height / 2)
    else:
        return (rectcenterx + copysign(1, endx) * width/2,
                rectcentery+ width/2 * endy / abs(endx))

print(rectclamp(6, 4, 12, 8, 9, 9))
print(rectclamp(6, 4, 12, 8, 27, 10))
print(rectclamp(6, 4, 12, 8, -12, -8))

>>>
(8.4, 8.0)               #top edge
(12.0, 5.714285714285714)   # right edge
(0.0, 0.0)   #corner
```